Unable to get KVM console keyboard and mouse working
I have been trying to set up a KVM console on my server rack, and I am having an issue with the cables. I have tried it with two different KVM consoles now, so I'm not sure that the KVM itself is the issue.
When I plug in a standard USB/VGA KVM Cable into one of the servers, I get an error
USB over-current condition
I have also tried a KVM cable that has VGA, USB, and PS/2 connectors. When I plug in the USB from that cable, I get
Unable to enumerate USB device
device descriptor read/64, error -71
repeated over and over.
When I plug in the PS/2 cables, nothing happens at all, and there is still no mouse and keyboard input. The video input on the console works fine.
After doing some research, I learned that Intel VT-D needed to be enabled in BIOS, so I did that, and I checked in Ubuntu that it is enabled, but no change. I have also tried it on different servers, still the same issue. I highly doubt that two different KVM consoles and two different cables are all broken, but I'm just not sure what the fix is here.
The KVM console is a Tripp-Lite B020-016-16, and the USB KVM cable is just a generic cable I got (which I suppose might explain the over-current error, but still odd). The PS/2 cable is the same brand as the KVM. Also, it's Ubuntu server 23.10. Am I just setting it up wrong? Does Ubuntu need another driver or additional software? I have to be missing something.

Can you get a KVM to USB / VGA cable from Tripp-Lite? Most KVM manufacturers have custom connectors on the KVM end of those cables.

unrelated side note: upgrade your Ubuntu. 23.10 is already end of life, the longer you wait the more difficult it will be to upgrade it to a supported release.

ps/2 is not plug and play, you need to reboot your device to get it working
